# How do I build a query filtered by associated data and also by field in original model in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to build a query in CakePHP 3.x. I have Articles that belongTo Authors (with author_id key in Articles table) and that belongToMany Authors through ArticlesAuthors. I want to select all articles that belong to a certain author_id and all the articles that also belong to that author in the ArticlesAuthors association.

jose_zap in the irc channel suggested using [leftJoinWith](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-leftjoinwith) but I'm not familiar enough with queries to understand how to do what I'm wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need `leftJoinWith` it will create the cross join of the rows, and the you can filter by the required conditions like this:

```
$query = $this->Articles->find('all')
  ->leftJoinWith('ArticlesAuthors')
  ->leftJoinWith('Authors')
  ->where(['Authors.id' => $authorId])
  ->orWhere(['ArticlesAuthors.author_id' => $authorId]);
```